# Expo React Native: There is no FCM API key configured for this project

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to setup push notifications for Android in my managed React Native Expo project. I have carefully followed the official guidelines [Push-notifications overview](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/) and [Using FCM for Push Notifications for Android](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/).

I have created a new firebase project for my Android application. Then in the Cloud Messaging tab of the firebase project, I copied the Server Key (FCM API Key). I also downloaded the generated `google-services.json` into my Expo project.

Then I started a new EAS build. But when I run, from terminal, `expo push:android:show`, I'm getting the title error:

```
There is no FCM API key configured for this project
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the command `expo push:android:show` is deprecated.
Instead I should use `eas credentials` , select the android platform and follow the instructions to display all my keys and credentials, including the `FCM API` key